# Entity with Secondary table, configuring pk join column. Can't match columns

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables:

```
monitors(id, unit_id, ...)
units(id, value)
```

where `unit_id` is foreign key to units' `id`. What I want is my entity class `Monitor` to have a String field `unit` mapped to units' `value` rather than a separate Unit entity field. This is what I have:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "monitors")
@SecondaryTable(name = "units",  
  pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(
                    name = "id",                  
                    referencedColumnName = "unit_id"))
public class Monitor {
private String unit;

...

@Column(table = "units", name = "value")
public String getUnit() {
    return unit;
}

public void setUnit(String unit) {
    this.unit = unit;
}
```

However, trying to run with this results in

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: 
Unable to find column with logical name: unit_id in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(monitors) 
and its related supertables and secondary tables

at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3JoinColumn.checkReferencedColumnsType(Ejb3JoinColumn.java:828)`
```

I'm using `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect` for dialect and `org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl` as physical naming strategy

What's going on here?

**Edit**:

If I instead swap the column names (as suggested below) like the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "monitors")
@SecondaryTable(name = "units",  pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id", name = "unit_id"))
public class Monitor {

...

@Column(name = "value", table = "units")
public String getUnit() {
    return unit;
}
```

I get `o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unknown column 'unit.unit_id' in 'on clause'`

and hibernate's query looks like this(prettified by me)
`select ...
from monitors monitor
left outer join 
units unit on monitor.id=unit.unit_id 
where ...`

The `on monitor.id=unit.unit_id` should be `on monitor.unit_id=unit.id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misusing/misunderstanding JPA Secondary Tables.
If you store a field of `Monitor` over in the secondary table `units`, then there will be no FK in the `monitors` table to point to it. The PK of `units` (`id`) will be a FK back to the PK of `monitors` (`id`). See [this reference](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_0/jpa/orm/secondary_tables.html).

The use of `referencedColumnName` is for cases where there is a composite PK in the entity table, so you have to map across the relative columns/fields (which you don't have either).

The only time you would have a FK in the table of the entity to represent a field is where you have a 1-1/N-1 relation. Secondary tables are not that case.

Answer (score 0):

You have switched the `name` and `referencedColumnName` in `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`.

`name` refers to the column in current table - but current table in the scope of `@SecondaryTable` is `units`. You can see it in the exception too - it's looking for `unit_id` (which you put as `referencedColumnName`) in `monitors`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, please see my edit above for the results of doing so.